# Regular expression in Python module looking for asterisk character is extremely slow

Tags: python, regex

**My working environment**:

```
OS: Windows 10 (64 bits)
RAM: 32 GB
Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1240 v5 @ 3.50 GHz
Python version: 3.7.4 (64 bits)
```

**Problem description**:

I'm working on a restful API log file. Users of this API, can specify `variableName:value` in their queries' URL and based on the variable name and the specified value, the search engine behind this API, would return the result. There is also a wildcard functionality allowing to create queries by using regular expressions which can have one of the following forms:

```
variableName:va*
variableName:*lue
variableName:*alu*
variableName:*
```

The purpose is to read a log file, then extract and count the number of lines containing **at least one occurrence** of one of the above mentioned patterns. This can give us an estimation so that we might be able to see what percentage of our users work with the wildcard functionality while querying our API.

For our analysis, it doesn't really matter how many occurrences of different variables (or maybe even same variables) appear on each line in the file (each line in the log file = one user query). As soon as one occurrence of one of the above mentioned patterns has been detected, the line is selected and our counter is incremented indicating that the wildcard functionality has been used in the query.

For the purpose of this analysis, I've developed a Python module with the following regular expression:

```
regexp_wildcard_asterisk = r"".join(
    [
        r"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*([:]|%3A)",
        r"(([*]|%2A)|[^=*]+([*]|%2A)|([*]|%2A)[^=*]+|",
        r"([*]|%2A)[^=*]+([*]|%2A))"
    ]
)
regexp_wildcard_asterisk_prog = re.compile(
    regexp_wildcard_asterisk, re.IGNORECASE
)
```

Given that queries are actualy http URLs, that's why in the above regular expression you can see %3A and %2A because depending on the encoding on the client side `:` and `*` can also be encoded as `%3A` and `%2A` respectively.

Then all I need to do, is to read the log file line by line, inside a loop and to check if there is a match:

```
with open(
        src_file,
        "r",
        encoding="UTF-8"
) as srcfile_desc:

    csv_reader = csv.reader(srcfile_desc, delimiter="|")

    wildcard_asterisk_func_counter = 0

    for tokens in csv_reader:

        # The pattern matching is done on the 5th colonne of each 
        # line, that's why I've written tokens[4]
        if (regexp_wildcard_asterisk_prog.search(tokens[4])):
            wildcard_asterisk_func_counter += 1
```

Well, this does the job, but it is **extremely slow!** Although I have to admit that sometimes my log files are quite huge, but still the size of the file doesn't explain the very very long execution time of this program. The last time I run the above program on a log file with only 890 lines and roughly 240 000 characters on each line (only a few lines with 1 100 000 characters). It took more than 24 hours and when I checked it was still running.

Now I know that regular expressions could indeed have impact on the performence, yet I've done pattern matching on other API logs files with millions of lines and sometimes with millions of characters on each line, looking for other characters such as `?, [, ], {, }` and the execution time never exceeded a few hours. So I thought maybe there is some bug in the definition of my regular expression looking for asterisk.

Reading my code, could you telle me, where do you think I've made a mistake (or mistakes)?

Comment: I suggest starting with replacing all grouping parentheses with non-grouping, since you aren't really interested in the contents of the matched groups. Also, you haven't mentioned why you treat `=` in a special way.

Comment: Instead of `[^=*]+` that includes linebreaks, I'd use `[^=*\r\n]+`

Comment: @ Błotosmętek Aren't the parenthesis rather mandatory here? For example consider the following : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*([:]|%3A) how without using the parenthesis the Alternation Operator (the "|" I mean) would understand that the OR condition is only between ":" and "%3A" but not what is before, that is, [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*? I thought (maybe I'm wrong) that this is the correct syntax, no? To answer your question about =, yes I have to remove it because there are cases where a query may include it after the : and the variable's name and these are to be excluded from counting.

Comment: @Toto You mean, linebreaks can have such impact on the overall execution time?

Comment: Not sure, but you're trying to match against the whole file. Some benchmark will be usefull.

Comment: @Toto OK, I'll give it a try. Yet if that turns out to be the cause of the problem, it would be quite strange as I read each time a single line and not the whole file in a single step as readlines() would do and therefore as I understand the lookup is done only on that line before continuing in the loop reading next lines.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the regex to remove capture groups and to not do anything that would attempt to search beyond line boundaries (I am only searching individual lines anyway). I am also using a regex that looks for the minimal match that will recognize a wildcard query. I timed my code twice using the OP's regex and the one below and found no appreciable difference for these 4 test cases. I removed the `re.IGNORECASE` flag as it was not serving any useful purpose.

I tried different variations for matching zero or more characters that were neither newline nor one of the asterisk characters (`*` or `%3A`) and there wasn't any appreciable timing change.

```
import re

# matches enough of the query to detect whether there was a wildcard:
regexp_wildcard_asterisk = r"""(?x) # Verbose mode
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+    # Match variable
(?::|%3A)               # Match ':'
(?:(?!\*|%2A).)*        # Match zero or more non-'*' non-newline characters
(?:\*|%2A)              # Match '*'
"""

regexp_wildcard_asterisk_prog = re.compile(
    regexp_wildcard_asterisk
)

lines = [
    'variableName:va*',
    'variableName:*lue',
    'variableName:*alu*',
    'variableName:*', # 1000 lines of these
]

from time import time
t1 = time()
for _ in range(300):
    wildcard_asterisk_func_counter = 0
    for line in lines:
        if (regexp_wildcard_asterisk_prog.search(line)):
                wildcard_asterisk_func_counter += 1
t2 = time()
print(t2 - t1)
```

[See Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w02F8c/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way I found is

```
^.*\w+(?::|%3A)[^=*]*?\*
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/gXkmzp/1/) (3 matches/83 steps/2 ms)

to be compared with yours with the same example text,

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/fMMClo/1/) (22 matches/476 steps/4 ms)